# Asp net, how do I list items in real time?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, fetch

I have the following view which displays the top 10 players ordered by their ranking.

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication3.Models.LiveRankingModel>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "LiveRanking";
}

<div style="text-align:center;">
    <h1><strong>Live Ranking</strong></h1>
</div>

<div style="display:flex; justify-content:space-around;">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    <div style="text-align: center; padding: 25px; border: 2px solid black; background-color: azure; border-radius: 25px; margin: 25px;">
        <div style="border:inherit;">
            <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(item.Image)" height="256" width="256" />
        </div>
        <hr />
        <h2>@item.Username</h2>
        <h3>@item.Score</h3>
    </div>
    }
</div>
```

Sorry for not listing my classes in an external .css file but, can I make it so that the clients don't have to reload the page to see the new results so I can also add a good looking transition effect when the players progress through the ranking?

Comment: Sure, use ajax!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got two options

1. You can use SignalR which is a MS library for ASP.NET project to add real-time functionality. the official website has a few good examples on how to use the library, [like this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-server-broadcast-with-signalr)
2. Or you can use Javascript setInterval + fetch (or jquery ajax)

   ```
   //this calls your api every 5 seconds
   //and retrieves your data to be rendered on the page
   setInterval(function(){
     fetch('api/your-endpoint')
   .then(function(response) {
     //your api should return an array of json object
     //here you iterate through the response object
     //create a new elemenet for each item
     //and append to an element already on the page
     //eg, create a an empty list on the page
     //and in here create li elements and append to it
   })
   .catch(function(err) {
     console.log(err);
   });
   }, 5000);
   ```